# Sharing single MySQL DB by two RestComm Connect instances?

Tags: mysql, restcomm

I have RestComm Connect configured to use an external MySQL DB (according to '[How to get started with Restcomm-Connect and Mysql](http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/configuration/How%20to%20get%20started%20with%20Restcomm-Connect%20and%20Mysql.html)'). The setup works fine (able to make Alice<->Bob calls via Olympus).

Now I would like to try out a new RestComm Connect release and configure it to use the same MySQL DB instance - i.e. to use the same 'restcomm' database (I want to share existing clients' accounts between the two RestComm instances).

So the target setup would be e.g.:

```
Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-8.2.0.1221 ---
                                 \
                                  --> MySQL DB ['restcomm' database]
                                 /
Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-8.2.0.1304 ---
```

In this case both RestComm instances share the same 'restcomm' database.

Is the above setup feasible, or are there instance specific data stored in the DB which can't be shared (i.e. besides tables such as restcomm_accounts or restcomm_clients)?

Of course only one of the RestComm instances would be running at given time.

Any tips, ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Dominik

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's designed to share the same DB, even with both or more instances active.